# Add jsonb key/value pair with uuid

Tags: postgresql, json, uuid

I am trying to add a new key value pair to a jsonb array and I am having some difficulties in doing it.
What I am trying to add is a key `id` with a `uuid` value

This is how my data looks right now:

```
{
    "id": "12c78bb5-8f81-49c0-b226-feb0164573c3",
    "type": "imageGalleryModule",
    "content": {
        "images": [{
            "title": "Mollit anim id est",
            "description": "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
        }, {
            "title": "Officia Deserunt",
            "description": "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
        }]
    }
}
```

And this is the result I am looking to achieve:

```
{
    "id": "12c78bb5-8f81-49c0-b226-feb0164573c3",
    "type": "imageGalleryModule",
    "content": {
        "images": [{
            "id": "6a1d15ad-468b-4714-81f8-dccffdea3021",
            "title": "Mollit anim id est",
            "description": "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
        }, {
            "id": "8099c2cf-2ff1-4855-9b54-aa0e62d4bfa5",
            "title": "Officia Deserunt",
            "description": "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
        }]
    }
}
```

So far I've only managed to add the `id` key with a static value using this query

```
select  jsonb(
                COALESCE(
                        jsonb_set(
                                imageElements,
                                '{id}',
                                jsonb '3',
                                true
                            ), imageElements
                    )
            )
from  jsonb_array_elements(
    (
        select entitiesArray->'content' -> 'images' from (
                select jsonb_array_elements(column) as entitiesArray from table
        ) as column
            where entitiesArray->> 'type' = 'imageGalleryModule'
    )
    ) as imageElements;
```

My question is, how can I generate a `uuid` for each key I am trying to add? Instead of my current static value `3` I want to add a `uuid` that must not be the same for all the elements in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem using this query:

```sql
select to_jsonb(array_agg(jsonb(
                COALESCE(
                        jsonb_set(
                                imageElements,
                                '{id}',
                                to_jsonb(uuid_generate_v4()),
                                true
                            ), imageElements
                    )
            )))
from  jsonb_array_elements(
    (
        select entitiesArray->'content' -> 'images' from (
                select jsonb_array_elements(column) as entitiesArray from table
        ) as column
            where entitiesArray->> 'type' = 'imageGalleryModule'
    )
    ) as imageElements;
```